# How to return value from Quartz Scheduler Job to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

In ASP.NET MVC Project, I have created a scheduler job, I am using Quartz.net 3.0.7

I need to know if this Job is finished executed to make some changes in the View or ASP.NET Form

I can know if my Job is finished by using Quartz Job Listener:

```cs
public Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();          
}
```

But I cannot use `ViewBag` or `Session` to pass value to detect that because it related to request and has life time and my Job may take long time.

Is there any way to do that or not?